# Custom Controls does not take the Design time Bounds height and width

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to do a pluralsight training that explains how to create a custom control for IOS. the training is using Swift but I'm doing the coding on xamarin. I'm facing an issue that I cannot solve and any input would be greatly appreciated. All the code can be found on this github project [CustomControls](https://github.com/AlexandreRoba/CustomControls)

Basically. I manage to have my custom control working at design time on the storyboard. I set the Width, the height and the constraint. But once I run the application the Bounds of the Frame of the control are both set to the default value which is 240x240 and my custom control which is a textbox looks like a square.

I do not understand why the values set at desing time on the designer are not making it through at the run time.

Design Time image:
[image]

Runtime Image:
[image]

The UIView with the incorect Bounds:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was happening. The Bounds are set at run time after the constructor is called (Obviously). The inner controls were set at the construction. I needed to overwrite the Bounds properties and to trigger the redesign of the inner controls every time the bounds change.

There might be a more elegant way to do this by overriding the view will appear... I'll try this.